# Identifying repeat interaction from two columns

Tags: interaction

I have two columns which contain investment bank names in joint debt offerings. I want to create a dummy variable if the Bank 1 & Bank 2 have recurring relationships.

Ex: if  Lehman Brothers & Goldman Sachs or Goldman Sachs & Lehman Brothers appear in column 2 & 3, Dummy = 1

Can anyone suggest a method to calculate this relationship?

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is presumably about a request for code in some unnamed software. It's not fit for migration elsewhere.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Can anyone suggest a software which I can use to address this matter. I have basic knowledge in stata and SAS.